# Call C# Async method from loop and ensure result go back to same thread. ThreadSafe

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am working on code performance optimizing. I have implemented `Task.WhenAll` in `MethodA` which calls `MethodB` which picks `await customersRecords`. Up to here is fine. In step I am looking through customerRecord and calling another method `await Task getCustomerRecordFilesLocation` to pick folders location by `customerRecord` but getting error that items with same key already defined. This is happening on multiple records.

If I replace `MethodA` with classic loop and `getCustomerRecordFilesLocation` with async call then I don't get error.

I believe ideally I want to ensure `getCustomerRecordFilesLocation` wait and it result goes back in correct thread?? I have tried `lock()` on `foreach(var customer in customerRecord)` code but still getting error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: g65434fr-5b5v-42wc-8a83-123456789054.

`MethodA`

```cs
public async Task<List<Customers>> MethodA(){
    List<Customer> customers = await GetAllCustomers();
    var inboundCustomerFiles= new List<InboundCustomerFiles>(); 

    await Task.WhenAll(customers.Select(async customer =>
        {
            var processedCustomer = await MethodB(customer);
            inboundCustomersFiles.AddRange(processedCustomer);
        });
}
```

`MethodB`

```cs
public static async Task<List<InboundCustomerFiles>> MethodB(Customer customer){
    var customerRecord = await GetCustomerRecord(customerId);

    foreach(var customer in customerRecord){
        var folderLocation = await Task.Run(() => getCustomerRecordFilesLocation(customerRecordId)); //Need help here... Get error key already  been added
    }
    return inboundCustomerFiles;
}
```

Comment: I would guess the error is somewhere else. The error message would match to a `Dictionary<,>` or `Hashset<>` when trying to add the same key twice, but there is nothing in your code example that uses such a structure. Run your code in debugger and enable all exception and take a look at the call stack to find the root cause of it.

Comment: if I run this code with classic loop instead of Task.WhenAll and getCustomerRecordFilesLocation with async call then I don't get error.

Comment: I am suspect result are mixed up in threads

Comment: Given the unused `var folderLocation =` in `MethodB`, I'm assuming there is deleted code there that uses a dictionary or a hashset...

Comment: How I ensure getCustomerRecordFilesLocation is only call when it is ready in loop and result only assign to correct thread?

Comment: What does it mean to be ready in loop?

Comment: What exactly does the method `getCustomerRecordFilesLocation` do? The contents may help us pinpoint the error. Also be careful with the line `inboundCustomersFiles.AddRange(processedCustomer);` as a `List` is not thread safe and adding items to it on multiple threads can cause loss of data.